# CURL returns response code 200 and 0 for a same page at different time

Tags: php, http, codeigniter, url, curl

I am facing one unusual behavior of curl. For a given page, I some times get HTTP response code as 200 and sometimes I get 0 as HTTP response code. I am not able to understand whether this page is valid or not. If you try the given code, please try it for at least 5-10 times so that you can see the difference.

```
function print_info()
{
    $url = 'bart.no';
    $arr = array(
    'bart.no',
    'bolandirekt.nu',
    'ekompassen.com',
    'ekompassen.nu',
    );

    foreach ($arr as $url)
    {
        echo "<br/>URL: " . $url;
        $temp = str_replace(array("www.", "http://", "https://"), "", strtolower($url));

        // From this array it will be decided which is to prepend
        $pre_array = array("", "www.", "https://", "http://", "https://www.", "http://www.");
        $status_code = array();

        // For each Value Status will be stored
        foreach ($pre_array as $pre)
        {

            $options = array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, // return web page
                CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE, // don't return headers
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE, // follow redirects
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "spider", // who am i
                CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => FALSE, // set referer on redirect
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, //ssl verify host
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, //ssl verify peer
                CURLOPT_NOBODY => FALSE,
                CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20, // timeout on connect
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20, // timeout on response
            );

            // Initializing Curl
            $ch = curl_init($pre . $temp);
            // Set Curl Options
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            // Execute Curl
            $content = curl_exec($ch);

            $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            echo "<pre/>";
            if ($code == 200)
            {
                print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
                break;
            }           
                            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }
}
```

So my final doubt is : Why I am getting response code 200 for the pages which are not existing Or not opening in browser ? Also, why sometimes I get response code 0 and sometimes response code 200 for the same page even if I keep time interval between requests ?

Comment: `0` is not a valid HTTP status code - you're most likely getting a timeout (maybe the page is slower to load than your 20 second timeout?).

Comment: You may also be getting firewalled due to multiple requests in a short time

Comment: It's normal to get different status codes at different times (caused by connection issues in most cases I've encountered).

Comment: This is too vague. Please mention which URL's fail in both your script (hint: `echo $pre . $temp;`) and the browser. Please note you'll have to call [`curl_error()`](http://nl3.php.net/curl_error) if `curl_exec()` returns `false`.

Comment: @codeCaster : for majority of the URLs, script considers `http://www`

Comment: @adam : If I try with time interval then also the same problem occurs.

Comment: @Vyktor: What if I run the same code from a server ? Then also I am having the same issue.

Comment: @nir the target server (whatever you put here `curl_init($pre . $temp);`) may have troubles. Network may be under huge load, server may be overloaded...

Comment: @Vyktor : but my point is like I am getting 200 response code for the pages which are not existing !!!

Comment: @nir what does it mean page is not existing? Does the page say that requested page doesn't exists? Does it really send back `4xx` family codes? Or dns doesn't exist at all?

Comment: @vyktor : It doesn't exist at all. I am managing thousands of domains. And out of them I have to find which are not active. I came to kn0w about the problem when I didn't get IP address of such pages. (obviously as they are not existing, I wont get IP address..)

Comment: what's with `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 0` ?

Comment: @goldenparrot : If i write it or not is of no meaning as I have provided CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION false.

Comment: @nir but the comment says 10 redirects!! anyway, could you update the question to put a single question describing your problem at the end? because, it's kinda difficult to figure what the problem is, after this long a discussion!

Comment: Obviously a network issue. Try using scraperwiki.com's network because it's believed to be reliably fast by many who use it. Test if your script works fine there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17733/discussion-between-nir-and-goldenparrot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CURL request did not complete, thus there's no response code.
The reason for this may be an invalid host name (can't resolve), malformed URL, timeout, etc.

You should be able to get the CURL error code as in CodeCaster's comment and curl_error / curl_errno docs.

Once the CURL request completed properly, then a response code (from the server) should be available and meaningful.

Comment: i am getting valid body responce but http code is 0 why ?